# Team Foundation Server - How to team build a Team Project but not pull all branches

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

Currently we have a team project setup like below (in regards to branches)

Team Project
    |__Developement
           |__Development - Isolated Feature Dev
           |__Main
                |__Production

The issue that i have, is that when we want to do a team build on the production branch solution, it copies the entire team project down to the build server (so 4x copies, 1 for each branch)  As the project is rather large, and the other branches are not required to be built, i'm wondering if there is any way to only build the single branch required?

Answer (score 6):

When you configure the build, on the workspace tab, choose the correct branch in source control.

Comment: Assuming this is TFS2008 you are dealing with.  For TFS2005 you need to look at the Workspace.xml file (but I would strongly recommend the questioner looks to upgrade to TFS2008)

Comment: Unfortunately we're on TFS 2005.  We're waiting for TFS 2010 to come out before upgrading due to the price.  TFS 2005 is such a pain in the ass sometimes!

Answer (score 2):

If you only want to check out the Development branch, configure the build to check out

```
$/Team Project/Development
```

If you want to check out a particular folder, but not sub-folders, you can 'Cloak' the sub-folders. Right click on the build from Team Explorer, chose "Edit Build Definition", and click the 'Workspace' tab.

From there you can cloak/add as many folders (branches are just folders) from as many places as you like